# What is the equivalent of going back (pop) through the pages in a GetX?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

What is the equivalent of going back (pop) through the pages in a GetX as a shown in the pic?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62lt9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use those features, you have two options.
Either something like this:

```
GetRouterOutlet.builder(
  builder: (context, delegate, currentRoute) {
    // your code
    // some navigation options are as it follows
    delegate.until(/home);
    delegate.toNamed('/shop');
    delegate.toNamed('/settings');
  }
```

or:

```
Get.toNamed("/home");
Get.offNamed("/shop");
Get.offAllNamed("/settings");
```

Find more here: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md

Comment: You are welcome. 
If this answer was helpful, could you please rate it and mark it as the correct one?
Thanks!